# How to reference assemblies that are in the GAC

Tags: asp.net, web-config, visual-studio-2005, assemblies, gac

In Visual Studio 2005, you need to add a new registry setting in order to see it in the Add Ref dialog box.

BUT

can you add a reference an assemble that are in the GAC in the `web.config` file?

i.e.

```
<system.web>
   <compilation>
       <assemblies>
          <add assembly="MNissen.DataControls, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e21df62f5c740a13"  />
          <add assembly="Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e21df62f5c740a13"  />
          <add assembly="Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e21df62f5c740a13"  />
          <add assembly="Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e21df62f5c740a13"  />
          <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e21df62f5c740a13"  />
    </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `<assemblies>` tag section in web.config.

Check this article for more info - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1.aspx

Comment: so whats the correct wat to add a ref? should you do it via the web.config file?

Answer (score 1):

Greg

I've created a sexy visual studio extension that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879/) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.

[image]

Regards...

Muse Extensions